# Counting a spacific value across multiple sheets and columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is my first time on this board so forgive my ignorance.

I am looking to modify the following formula. I am using

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&C2:C13&"'!m:m"),A39))
```

to count how many times the value in A39 appears in column M across multiple sheets.

Is there a way to also check columns O,R,T,V,X,Z,AB,AD and AF for the same value and give me a grand total?

Comment: Why not use range M:AF in the formula? Is there any chance that the value in A39 can also be found in the columns you have skipped?

Comment: So just to add some context to this I have a workbook with monthly tabs. On those tabs Columns M,O,R,T,V,X,Z,AB,AD and AF track dates of interactions on the monthly sheet. The sheet range is represented on my totals page in C2:C13. So I am trying to count how many times a date is entered on the sheets. The above formula works fine to count the dates on all sheets but only in one column. I need a grand total of all sheets and all 10 columns. Thank you in advance for the assistance.

Comment: No reason at all @sktneer!!!! I was over complicating it. That has always been my issue. That looks to work wonderfully.

Comment: Glad it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey Juan the most easier is,

=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A2:A6,D2)+COUNTIF(Sheet10!A2:A6,D2)+COUNTIF(Sheet15!A2:A6,D2).

Or in addition write this one, anywhere in blank area like in C2 to C4 write your sheet name. 
In E2 write Value to count. 
In F2 write this formula 
=SUMPRODUCT (COUNTIF (indirect ("'"&C2:C4&'"! A2 :A20"), E2))

NB RANGE A2 TO A20 will be searched for Value to Count.

Answer (score 0):

Now to add another dynamic to this problem. I now need to count how many times a specific name appears on the date that is counted. the name would be in fields N:AG. I tried just doubling up the code to count both but the number it came back with makes no sense. This is what I came up with...

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'"&C2:C13&"'!N:AG"),F2‌​),COUNTIFS(INDIRECT(‌​"'"&C2:C13&"'!N:AG")‌​,E2))
```